# Mount overlay directory containing NFS shared mount

Tags: nfs, overlayfs

I have a directory `/tmp/usr/usr`. In this path I mount NFS share from an other machine:

```
mount -t nfs IP:/export_path/usr /tmp/usr/usr
```

The contents of the remote `/usr` is there. But when I try to create an overlay filesystem and mount only `/tmp/usr`, the contents disappear:

```
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/tmp/usr,.... /merged
```

I expected to see `/merged/usr/...`, but `/merged` is empty.
I tried this without NFS mount and it worked without problems (I created a local directory structure), so I think that is a feature of overlay.

Could someone explain and help?

Best Regards, Kamil